# Want to float the "Subscribe" button to the right of the input field

Tags: html, css, forms, field, mailchimp

I'm kinda new to HTML/CSS and have been trying for hours to float the "submit" button to the right of the input form field. I'm sure this is a relatively easy fix, I just can't seem to figure it out. Please help :)

I've attached a screenshot of what I want it to look like.
[layout of subscribe button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIxiJ.png)

```css
.footer-wrapper #mc_embed_signup {
 & input {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="//methodpgh.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=5a5764ee5b831b0dbfd47811f&amp;id=11148dcbc6" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
     
    <div class="mc-field-group">
     <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email Address">   <div class="clear submit-btn"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
    
     <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
      <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
      <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
     </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_5a5764ee5b831b0dbfd47811f_11148dcbc6" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        
        
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clear="class"` can be used when you do not want content on both the sides of the element. This class was stopping the button to get aligned to the right of the input field. I did removed it, so its working now. :)

```css
.footer-wrapper #mc_embed_signup {
 & input {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="//methodpgh.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=5a5764ee5b831b0dbfd47811f&amp;id=11148dcbc6" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
     
    <div class="mc-field-group">
     <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email Address">   <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </div>
    
     <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
      <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
      <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
     </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_5a5764ee5b831b0dbfd47811f_11148dcbc6" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        
        
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!